# Insertar registros en tablas relacionadas simultaneamente laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual, necesito generar una cotizacion, esta tabla cotizaciones esta relacionada con la tabla cliente, logre hacerlo generando el cliente aparte y trayendo los datos al formulario donde se genera la cotizacion, el detalle es que es poco practico generar el cliente aparte y luego la cotizacion, como podria hacer para que el usuario seleccione si es un cliente nuevo o uno previo y en caso de ser nuevo poder generarlo dentro del mismo form.

QuotationController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\quotation;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\product;
  use App\Client;
  use App\coated;
  use App\material;


 class QuotationController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $quotations= quotation::paginate('10');

    return view('admin.quotations.index', compact('quotations'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{

 $products = product::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $coateds = coated::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $materials = material::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $clients = Client::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('admin.quotations.create',compact('products','coateds','materials','clients'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'description'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
        'tax'=>'required',
        'sub_total'=>'required',
        'total'=>'required',
        'quantity'=>'required',
        'client_id'=>'required',
        'product_id'=>'required',
        'material_id'=>'required',
        'coated_id'=>'required',

      ]);

     $requestValues = $request->all();
           $quotation = quotation::create([
              'description'=>$requestValues['description'],
              'price'=>$requestValues['price'],
              'tax'=>$requestValues['tax'],
              'sub_total'=>$requestValues['sub_total'],
              'total'=>$requestValues['total'],
              'quantity'=>$requestValues['quantity'],
              'client_id'=>$requestValues['client_id'],
              'product_id'=>$requestValues['product_id'],
              'material_id'=>$requestValues['material_id'],
              'coated_id'=>$requestValues['coated_id'],


            ]);



 return redirect()-> route('admin.quotations.edit')->with('info','Cotizacion guardada con exito');

}
```

Quotation Model

```
   namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class quotation extends Model
 {

protected $table = 'quotations';

  protected $fillable = [
   'description', 'price', 'tax', 'sub_total', 'total','quantity', 
   'client_id','product_id','coated_id','material_id'
   ];

  public function client()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
 }

 }
```

Archivo Route

```
 Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('admin/home',function(){
        return view('admin.home');
         })->name('admin');

   //----------------------------------Cotizaciones------------------------------------      
Route::post('admin/quotations/store','QuotationController@store')->name('quotations.store')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.create');

    Route::get('admin/quotations','QuotationController@index')->name('quotations.index')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.index');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/create','QuotationController@create')->name('quotations.create')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.create');

    Route::put('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@update')->name('quotations.update')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.edit');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/show/{quotation}','QuotationController@show')->name('quotations.show')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.show');

    Route::delete('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@destroy')->name('quotations.destroy')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.destroy');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@edit')->name('admin.quotations.edit')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.edit');
```

Comment: Compañero, no me queda clara cual es tu pregunta, ¿podrías ponerla con algun ejemplo o de otra manera?. (OFFTOPIC) Igualmente el código esta muy bien estructurado, solo te recomendaría que usaras PSR4 (esto lo hacen los IDE solo) para tabular todo bien.

Comment: Buenos dias amigo, te explico cuando el usuario va a generar la cotizacion esta esta relacionada a un cliente como si fuese una factura, lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de generar la cotizacion la persona que la va a crear pueda seleccionar si es para un cliente nuevo o si es para uno previo (hasta los momentos lo logre hacer con un cliente previo).pero necesito las 2 opciones dentro del crud de la cotizacion por que seria poco factible crear el cliente aparte y luego la cotizacion

Comment: Porque simplemente no lo buscas con un `$cliente = Cliente::find($id)` y luego si no existe lo creas (`if(is_null($cliente)){ $cliente = new Cliente();/* datos aqui */ $cliente->save() }`). Tambien indagaria sobre el findOrCreate de Laravel

Comment: Entiendo la idea mas o menos pero como haria para plasmarlo en el codigo de manera que el usuario pueda seleccionar, disculpa mi ignorancia pero realmente tengo poco tiempo programando en laravel y no me termina de quedar claro del todo